# Sonar Security - Array is stored directly :: why issue in array only in ArrayList?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have 4 classes

```
Class A {    
    public void setMyArray(String[] myArray) { 
      this.myArray = myArray; 
    }
}

Class B {    
    public void setMyArrayList(ArrayList myArray) { 
      this.myArray = myArray; 
    }
}
Class C {
  public void setX(int x) { 
  this.myX = x; 
}}
 Class D {    
public void setX(Integer x) { 
  this.x = x; 
}
```

}

Sonar reports an issue on the first class  Only  "Array is stored directly"

but sonar did not report the same issue on the second class . I wonder Why ?

Answer (score 3):

Because anyone can modify the external array.

With a list, you have the choice of passing in an un-modifiable list to get around that problem while still having the ease of external access if you -want-.

So the problem does exist with the second case, but it's much less common, and can more easily be avoided.

There are other problems with using a raw array. If the array needs to grow, and you also want external access, you don't have that anymore - they're pointing to the old array, not your new expanded array. With a list, that's all encapsulated.

Comment: Your answer would be correct if the argument was of type List. But it's of type ArrayList. And except by suclassing ArrayList and redefining all the mutating methods, there's no way to make an ArrayList unmodifiable. So FindBugs could generate a similar warning here.

Comment: @ZinabTaher: you can't modify an int from the outside: it's a primitive type passed by value. And an Integer is immutable, so even if you keep a reference of that Integer, you can't modify it.

Comment: @JBNizet All it cares about is whether its an array or some kind of Object reference. Because using an array in the way described is so common, and is such a common source of bugs, it specifically checks for that condition. While the same thing could happen with an ArrayList (or any List for that matter) that isn't something that's being checked for because it's a *less common* (although perhaps still a common) source of bugs.